# public folder that auto replies only works for internal mail

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, public-folders

My Auto reply public folder only replies to internal mail. External mail makes it to the folder, but from an external test account, we do not get a reply. Where can I begin to look to find where this problem is. I wish this public folder to reply to everyone who sends a message to it.

Comment: Do you get external out of office messages to regular mailboxes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, we do not have any issues with out of office messages.

Comment: It seems that no!! OOR do not seem to be working?! * completely shocked* Where can I go from here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I nuked the exchange box, and rebuilt if from scratch - worked so much faster and better.

Lesson learned: If you know you can build it better, do so!

Answer (score 0):

Require sender authentication is ON?

Check setup here:
http://www.bug-man.org/exchange-server-auto-reply-from-distribution-group-via-public-folder/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.